# ODBC Data Source Administrator Crashes

Tags: crash, odbc, datasource

I've got a user in my organization that experiences a crash in ODBC Data Source Administrator when he clicks the File DSN tab. This has been happening for the past 2 months.

The program will just hang forever and will "stop working" when I try to force close it. OS is Windows 7 Pro 64-bit.

The 32 and 64 bit driver versions are installed and both versions of the program crash when this happens.

Event Viewer shows a .NET Runtime error 1026 at the same time of the crash. Updating/uninstalling and reinstalling .NET did no good.

SFC/scannow didn't show any results.
Tried replacing a potentially corrupt .dll file but that didn't work either.

I've got threads open in the Spiceworks and Microsoft Communities; but none have done me much good.

NEW CONTENT:

In Event Viewer

Faulting application name: odbcad32.exe, version: 6.1.7600.16385

Faulting module name: ole32.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514

Still needing help with this please.

Comment: Any luck resolving this issue? I'm experiencing the same issue with the exact same fault information in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution. Microsoft issued a hotfix for ole32.dll causing programs to crash. Information and download link are available here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2541119

Comment: I found the same hotfix, unfortunately it's been superceded by later updates but this issue still occurs (though perhaps due to a different root cause in our case).

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC shortcuts point to %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe
This is the version that crashes.

The version in %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
works allright!
If the ODBC administrator in SysWOW64 works allright for you, you might consider changing your shortcuts to point to that location.

Comment: That was the first thing we tried. No dice. See my above respornse. That was our fix.

Comment: This is not a useful answer. The file in system32 is 64 bit and the file in SysWOW64 is 32 bit. The files are not interchangeable. 32 bit applications require 32 bit ODBC and 64 bit applications require 64 bit ODBC. Attempting to swap the files will break things very badly.